# Fastest way to solve a linear system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following homogeneous linear system of two first order ODE's :
$$\begin{cases} x'(t) = f(t)\,y(t) \\ y'(t)=-f(t)\,x(t)\end{cases} $$
for a given smooth function $f$.

One possibile method to solve it should be to compute the exponential of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0 & F(t) \\ -F(t) & 0\end{pmatrix}$, where $F'(t)=f(t)$.

Is there a faster way? For example, if $f=c$ is constant, then we have a single second order ODE to solve:
$$ x''(t) = c\,y'(t) = -c^2\,x(t) \;$$
which can be easily done by solving the associated algebraic equation $\lambda^2=-c^2\,$.

Comment: $z'(t)=-if(t)z(t)$ with $z=x+iy$ is a separable equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with only 2 unknown functions $x, y$, a common trick is to set $z = x + iy$ and try to see if $z$ satisfies and ODE. Here :

$$ z' = x' + i y' = f ( y - i x) = - i f z $$

Therefore, you come back to $z' = gz$ with $g = -if$. Note that this is specific to this case and cannot be adapted to very general situations. Solving for $z$ with initial condition $z(0) = x(0) + iy(0)$ allows you to recover ultimately $x$ and $y$ by taking its real and imaginary parts.

Of course this does not work anymore if $x$ and $y$ are not real-valued.